# Is there an off-the-shelf database solution similar to asihollywooddatabase.com or imdb?

Tags: database

What off-the-shelf database solutions would allow me to do the same thing as [asihollywooddatabase](http://www.asihollywooddatabase.com) or something similar to [IMDB](http://imdb.com) without having to write the software from scratch.

I have little knowledge of html or website design so something without these requirements would be preferred.

Comment: If you are looking to duplicate **just the database** part of the site, you can do this with pretty much any Database Management Software out there.  If you are looking to create a user interface similar, then that has nothing to do with the database.  I suggest you talk to someone who understands website design and have them walk you through all the components of a website.

Answer (score 0):

What are you going to actually do with the data, if you just want to save it to look at yourself and run simple(r) queries then microsoft access as part of office suite is a great tool, if your building a website, mysql is free to use and has alot of help and guidance available on the internet.

either way dont try and do it all yourself, if you get stuck, google is your friend ;)